# Using Selenium and Python, how do I access the price values in the store ID on this webpage?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm struggling to access the store values (i.e. 15, 100, 500, 2,000, etc) on this page. I'm trying to use a for loop to access the values and append them to a list, however it looks like it's adding all the store item descriptions and values as one whole item into a list.[image: Here's an image of the webpage I'm scraping][image: Here's my code]

I tried a for loop however it's adding everything as one item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your selector `#store` is selecting the whole `div` with the ID of `store` and when you do `entry.text` it's the giant item with all the elements that's being converted to a string.
You'll have to do something like `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#store .grayed b")`. You can then iterate over this list and process your items.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. I'm curious, why did you use .grayed b as the class? How could you tell from the HTML page that was the correct name for the class?

Comment: Try to use the most specific CSS selectors when scraping, I could've escaped using just `b`, but that would've selected all the `<b>` tags on the page . Look up CSS selectors for more info!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Selenium for a long time, but  I recall being able to locate items via their XPath, which you can get by right clicking the element in the inspect menu and going to copy -> copy XPath. Maybe if you look at the XPaths of each price or item and spot a pattern to be able to modify the XPath to get the next item's XPath?

Sorry if this isn't helpful

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/